# Making lines to copy the Torah

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, safrus

Do the Scriptures themselves say to write lines when making a copy of the Torah, or if this is an oral tradition?

Comment: How do you define _Scriptures_? Most details of most laws come from the Oral Law which complements the Written Law.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing where this is said anywhere (written or oral). I asked this question though because someone told me it said this in the Torah itself, but I could not find it. But I thought maybe they meant one of the other writings instead...

Comment: It's important to note, that we don't "write" lines when making a copy of the Torah. The appropriate word would be to "score" lines into the parchment. [Score = a line (such as a scratch or incision) made with or as if with a sharp instrument].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for this information in [Maimonides, Hil. Sefer Torah 1:12:](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Tefillin,_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.1.12)

> הֲלָכָה לְמשֶׁה מִסִּינַי שֶׁאֵין כּוֹתְבִין סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה וְלֹא מְזוּזָה אֶלָּא בְּשִׂרְטוּט:
>
> It is a rule dating back to Moses who received it on Sinai<sup>1</sup> that a
> Torah scroll or Mezuzah may only be written on parchment that has
> **lines**.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Law given to Moses at Sinai](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_given_to_Moses_at_Sinai)

Comment: Might be worth expanding on the defintion of הלכה למשה מסיני

Comment: The _scriptures_ source would then be the Yerushalmi Talmud, as the Rambam's commentators note.

Answer (score 2):

This is not mentioned anywhere in the Written Law - but it's well documented in the Oral Law, in this case in the Talmud.

See, for example, [Megila 16b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.16b.15?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which states:

> דברי שלום ואמת אמר רבי תנחום ואמרי לה אמר רבי אסי מלמד שצריכה שרטוט כאמיתה של תורה
>
> With regard to what is stated: “Words of peace and truth” ([Esther 9:30](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Esther.9.30?lang=bi)), Rabbi Tanḥum said, and some say that Rabbi Asi said: This teaches that a Megilla scroll requires scoring, i.e., that **the lines for the text must be scored onto the parchment, as the Torah itself, i.e., as is done in a Torah scroll.**

Comment: Some interpret אמיתה של תורה as a Mezuza not a Torah scroll

Comment: Those Rishonim that interpret אמיתה של תורה as a Mezuza not a Torah scroll, also require scoring for a Torah scroll, albeit a more limited form of scoring. https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%95%D7%98_%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%AA%22%D7%9D#מחלוקת_הראשונים